# How could I recreate the proof of the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

I saw a proof of the Dominated Convergence Theorem that goes like this:

If $X_n \to X$, $|X_n| \le Y $, and $E[Y] < \infty$, prove that $E[X_n] \to E[X]$.

First, define $Z_n = X_n + Y$. Then, 
$$\liminf Z_n = \liminf (X_n + Y) = \liminf X_n + Y  = X + Y := Z$$

By assumption $Z$ is always positive since $Y \ge |X|$ and applying Fatou's lemma,

$$\liminf E[Z_n] \ge E[Z]$$
$$\liminf E[X_n + Y] \ge E[X + Y] $$
$$\liminf E[X_n] \ge E[X]$$

Now define $W_n = Y - X_n$ and
$$\liminf W_n = \liminf (Y-X_n) = Y - \liminf X_n  = Y - X:= W$$

$W$ is always positive and proceeding like above we have that

$$\liminf(-E[X_n]) \ge E[X_n] $$
$$-\limsup(E[X_n])\ge -E[X_n] $$
$$\limsup E[X_n] \le E[X_n] $$

Putting everything together, we get

$$\liminf E[X_n] \ge E[X] \ge \limsup E[X_n] $$

Since $\limsup a_n \ge \liminf a_n$ for any sequence,

$$\liminf E[X_n] = E[X] = \limsup E[X_n] $$

Because both $\liminf E[X_n]$ and $\limsup E[X_n]$ are equal, the limit exists and
$$\lim E[X_n] = E[X] $$
Which completes the proof.

I understand the logic and all the steps, but suppose I am staring at the assumptions and the conclusion only, without the answer laid out in front of me. How can I tell that defining $Z_n$ and $W_n$ and proceeding like above is a good idea and something I should try? What's the mental process that would have put me on the right path to a solution here (and in similar problems of course!)?

Comment: I would summarize the main idea as, "taking out the absolute values". For two real numbers $a,b$, $|a|\leq b$ iff $a+b\geq 0, a-b\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing Fatou's lemma, which applies for non-negative sequences, we want to use it with such sequences related to $X_n$ and $Y$. Since $Y$ bounds the absolute value of $X_n$, it is natural to use this with $Y_n:=Y\pm X_n$.
 Then in the bound we will be able to put the integral of $Y$ outside the $\liminf$.